# VBA if Else within For Next

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

```
        'I don't know how to write the code, but this is the goal:

        'Loop through cells A1 to A10. 
        'Test if cell A1 meets condition. 
        'If not, go to A2. 
        'If yes, do procedure, then go to A2. 

        Sub TestForIfElse()

        Dim Counter As Integer
        Dim Counter2 as Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To 5

            Counter = i

            If Counter > 3 Then  'GOTO NEXT i LOOP

        Next i   'ERROR MSG NEXT WITHOUT FOR

            Else

            Counter2 = Counter2 + i

            End If

        Next i   'GOTO NEXT i LOOP

    End Sub
```

Expected:  Run For Next loop.
           Within the loop test for condition.
           If the condition is met, go to the next For loop.
           If the condition is not met,  do something else, then go to  the 
           next for loop.
Error message as marked on code block.

Comment: Get rid of the first `Next i` and the `Else` and change the condition to be `<=3`.

Comment: You cannot interleave loops

Comment: Respect the block structure. Even if it's 'Basic' ... ;)

Comment: Learn about other types of loop (`While`, `Until`). Understanding looping is a fundamental of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you attempting this is breaking the block structure for [for loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement).

Based on your comments below, you can loop each cell inside your `Range("A1:A10")` and do your validation in that loop. If it contains the value "*" then call your procedure. Otherwise, your loop will move on to the next cell reference in your range.

```
Sub TestingLoops()

    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        If InStr(Cell.Value, "*") > 0 Then
            SomeProcedure Target
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

The procedure you call can take in your `range` reference or it's value if you need those. Here is an example where I passed the reference to the `range`.

```
Private Sub SomeProcedure(ByRef Target As Range)
    'do something
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate. Maybe what I am trying to do cannot be done in nested loops. I want to do an i loop and test for a condition, and if met, perform a procedure.  If not met go to to the next i.  Maybe I have to run FirstLoop and identify the cells that qualify for the procedure, then come back in a SecondLoop procedure on those cells.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56705094/edit) your code and include what you are actually trying to accomplish? That might give better direction and you can get an answer more direct to your needs.

Comment: Loop through cells A1 to A10.  Test if cell A1 contains Character *. If not, go to A2.
if yes, do procedure, then go to A2.